# application.conf for Scala SBT Akka Actors

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I was wondering.. where do you put the `application.conf` file that configures actors in a file? I'm trying to do what is being done [here](http://typesafe.com/resources/getting-started/tutorials/getting-started-with-akka-scala.html#overriding-configuration-externally-optional) but SBT is not picking up on the file - I was under the impression that SBT will find the `application.conf` and automatically add it to my `-classpath`. I currently have `application.conf` in `/project/application.conf`

The error I'm getting is:

```
[ERROR] [04/11/2012 16:08:13.174] [HittingTimeSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://HittingTimeSystem/user/master] error while creating actor
akka.config.ConfigurationException:router Actor[akka://HittingTimeSystem/user/master/workerRouter] needs external configuration from file (e.g. application.conf)
```

Thanks!
-kstruct

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It should end up on the classpath if you put it in `src/main/resources/application.conf`

Comment: Worked! I also had a problem in my `application.conf` file where I was doing /router/ instead of /master/router/ since my router was a "child" of another actor "master"

Answer (score 0):

just update:

```
//  val conffactory = ConfigFactory.load() //  from 'src/test/resources' if 'sbt test'
//  val conffactory = ConfigFactory.load() //  from 'src/main/resources' if 'sbt run'
    val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("config/application.conf")).getConfig("my") // from '/config' where / - root of app
```